# Set a timer for Fused Location provider onLocationChanged

Tags: android, android-studio, location, android-location, android-thread

I am using FusedLocationClient for the location. I have noticed that some times it takes too much time for onLocationChanged() to get called because of whatever issues. Is there any good way that i can put a timer on that, for example if i don't get the onLocationChanged() callback after 10 seconds it will show the location fetching failed. I know I can user thread but what I am looking for is better solution like some type of api method or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just simply use the handler.postDelayed() method.